# Opening document from a stream

Tags: stream, vsto, powerpoint, isolatedstorage

Is there a way to open a presentation from a stream, memory file or isolated storage?

I have a presentation file that I want to open in PowerPoint, but do not want to allow user to access the file itself. Unfortunately the `Presentations.Open()` function of PowerPoint (and `Open()` of all other Office applications) only accepts a path parameter, which means I must save the file somewhere on the disk and then open it in PowerPoint, which will consequently give user access to the file.

Has anyone done this in any Office application?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to open the file from a URL (one that's not exposed to the user)?  That would still leave a temp file on the user's HDD, at least for the length of time the presentation's open, possibly longer, so might not be acceptable.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: Yes, that temp file is not acceptable. Office applications always show path of the documents in the Office Backstage (Info tab), making it so very trivial to know where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenXML SDK to [open documents from a stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478386.aspx), but not from within an Office application.

But, if you're motivated enough, you could delete the file after it's closed. It's pretty simple, you just need to create a separate process and wait for the file to not be locked for writing any more. Or, if you know when it's closed (e.g. if you do the closing in code), you may not need a separate process.

Comment: But while the file is open in the application, Office application will always be showing its path, thus making it easy to copy it.

Comment: You're right. You can't prevent them from copying it. If the powerpoint you're opening is a VSTO template/document, you could set some document properties or variables to make the document auto-close if it was not opened in the approved way, but there are ways around this too. There really is no way to completely control it.